# Submit PHP Query From Single Page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, forms

I'm currently trying to create a form that will create user accounts and save them into a database. The page where I create the form is called through a jQuery .load function and so I need my form to operate within a single page, but I'm not sure how?
This form is on one page, let's call it the **registration** page. And then it calls an action to controller.php which is on another page, how do I go about avoiding this problem?

```
<form id="controlForm" name="controlForm" method="post" action="controller.php">
  <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <th>First Name </th>
      <td><input name="fname" type="text" class="textfield" id="fname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Surname </th>
      <td><input name="sname" type="text" class="textfield" id="lname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="124">Login</th>
      <td width="168"><input name="login" type="text" class="textfield" id="login" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Password</th>
      <td><input name="password" type="password" class="textfield" id="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Confirm Password </th>
      <td><input name="cpassword" type="password" class="textfield" id="cpassword" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="ip" type="hidden" class="textfield" id="ip" value="<?php
      function ip(){if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){$ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];}else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){$ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];}else{$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];}return $ip;}
$ip = ip();
/* Gathering Data Variables */
    $ip = $ip;
    echo($ip)
  ?>"/></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Create Account" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

After I clean all the variables on the controller page, they create the query as follows:

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO control(login, type, verify, vcode, passwd, ip, cDate, first_name, surname,uID) VALUES('$login','$type','$verify', '$vCode','".md5($_POST['password'])."','$ip','$cdate','$fname','$sname','AC-$uid')";
$result = @mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $qry);
//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    header("location: #/Created");
    exit();
}else {
    echo("Creation Failure");
}
```

This is some script from the second page, but essentially, how would I go about loading everything from the controller page to create this form on one page that is called through jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('body').on('#controlForm','submit',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 //Initate ajax 
 var actionUrl = $(this).attr('action'); //get the action of the form
 var data = $(this).serialize();

  $.ajax({
      url : actionUrl,
      type: 'post',
      data: data,
      success: function(){
         //Do What you want after submit
      } 
 }); //added spacing
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to use ajax to post data, and get a response, and then change the page based on response?

So you want to prevent the form submit default like this

```
$('#controlForm').on('submit',function(e){ //Here added single quote
     e.preventDefault();
     //Initate ajax 
     var url = $(this).attr('action'); //get the action of the form

      $.ajax({
          url : url,
          type: 'post',
          data: { /*get data from form and put it here */ },
          success: function(){
             //Do success logic, hooray user signed up!
          } 
});
```

And then just send your form over via ajax.
I'm fairly certain you don't want to do this.
I'm no expert but I believe that sending a password and email registration 
through ajax is bad practice.

If you don't know about ajax look it up on jQuery docs.

Hope I'm understanding your question!

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var input1 = $('#input1').val();
    ...

    $.post('myPHP.php', {sendInput1: input1 ...})
        .done(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
});
```

or

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var form = $('form').serialize();

    $.post('myPHP.php', {all: form})
        .done(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$input1 = (isset($_POST['input1'])) ? $_POST['input1'] : die('Not provided the input1');
...
```